# Not valid month in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with date and time while inserting, it's showing it is a not valid month. What should I do?

```
Insert into PEPSIRENDEEMHISTORY(
   PIN,
   STATUS,
   CURRENTDATE,
   MSISDN,
   USERNAME,
   SIM
)
VALUES(
   '4501664170',
   1,
   '5/12/2013 8:05:26 PM',
   '2348121846632',
   'ranjith-PC\ranjith',
   1
)
```

Comment: Simply put you're not inserting a date, you're inserting a _string_. Convert it to a date as Chris has suggested.

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm)

Assuming that `currentdate` is a timestamp, you'd want to insert it in the following manner:

```
TIMESTAMP '2013-05-12 20:05:26'
```

Your query, then, would be

```
INSERT INTO PEPSIRENDEEMHISTORY(PIN,STATUS,CURRENTDATE,MSISDN,USERNAME,SIM)
    VALUES ('4501664170', 1, TIMESTAMP '2013-05-12 20:05:26', '2348121846632', 'ranjith-PC\ranjith', 1);
```

To keep it in the format you're inserting it as, you can use (as per [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#i1006817))

```
TO_DATE('5/12/2013 8:05:26 PM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS am')
```

Comment: Using TO_DATE() will _not_ keep it in the same "format", a date has not format only methods of display.

Comment: @Ben I think Chris meant to keep the same format of the *literal* as the ANSI date/timestamp literal require an ISO formatted date/timestamp